# PHP time difference in 24h clock system problem

Tags: php, time

im trying to calculate the time between two different times and output them in hours. It will be displayed to the customer to see how much time the service will take.

Thats my code:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime($timeFROM);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($timeTO);
$interval = $datetime2->diff($datetime1);
$hour_decimal = number_format(intval($interval->format('%H')) + round(intval($interval->format('%I')) / 60, 2), 2, '.','');
echo $hour_decimal;
```

The code works fine for classic jobs, but for work at night its getting complicated because if the second time value (`$timeTO`) is after 00:00 it calculates from `$timeTO` to `$timeFROM` instead of `$timeFROM` to `$timeTO`.

Example:

```
$timeFROM = "6:00";
$timeTO = "8:00";
```

output = 2.00
That would be correct.

Example 2:

```
$timeFROM = "23:30";
$timeTO = "1:00";
```

output = 22.50 And thats wrong. It should be 1.50

Looks like I need to force the function to always calculate from `$timeFROM` to `$timeTO` and not the other way around, no matter which value is bigger.

Anyone an idea? Couldn't find anything in google and also didn't know how to ask google for that exactly. Sorry when the solution might be very easy!

Greetings

Comment: If you can, use full date and time data

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the full date. The customers picks the time for the service only. it would be much work to save the date here aswell. Would be great if there is another solution

Comment: Cant you just append a *fake* date to the time?

Comment: No it is not possible :( I could check if one of the times is past 00:00 and add a day to it but it could also happen to have two times like "01:00" to "03:00".

Comment: Even if it does not answer to your question, I would recommand you to take a look at the [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/) library which is really great to handle dates and times in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 24 hours if datetime2 is less than datetime1 if you only want forward calculations:

```
if ($datetime2 < $datetime1) {
    $datetime2->add(new DateInterval("PT24H"));
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you, I totally forgot about that! Works like a charm